# Interpreting Kendall-Theil Sen Siegel Nonparametric Linear Regression from RStudio and writing up APA style

Tags: r, regression

I am a newbie when it comes to stats and I am performing Kendall-Theil Sen (Siegel variation) linear regressions for my dissertation. I am really not sure how to interpret the output and google hasn't offered much help either. I know the estimate reflects the regression coefficients but I am completely oblivious as how to write this up correctly.

This is my output for one regression:

```
Call:
mblm(formula = SCI_TotalScore ~ DefeatTotalScore, dataframe = complete_dat_totals)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.6089  -4.0464  -0.3589   6.1411  14.3911 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate     MAD V value Pr(>|V|)    
(Intercept)       23.8589  7.6916  4095.0  < 2e-16 ***
DefeatTotalScore  -0.2500  0.2553   245.5 1.05e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.247 on 88 degrees of freedom
```

Can anyone offer any help?